# Scalacheck [Error] : error while loading Gen, class file is broken

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to use Scalacheck, the Gen class for generate data in my code but I have this error when I compile :

> [Error] : error while loading Gen, class file
> 'C:\Users\D721628.m2\repository\org\scalacheck\scalacheck_2.13\1.14.3\scalacheck_2.13-
> 1.14.3.jar(org/scalacheck/Gen.class)' is broken

It's a maven project.
Can you have the solution or I can execute my code with spark-shell but I don't know how to import Scalacheck library in the spark-shell console.

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>



<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <!-- This plugin compiles Scala files -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- This plugin compiles Java files -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- disable surefire -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- enable scalatest -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
      
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>only</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/assembly/jar-with-deps-with-exclude.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-install-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalacheck/scalacheck -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalacheck</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalacheck_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-resources-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't use Scalacheck with Spark so ?

Comment: The error is unrelated to _Spark_ (but that doesn't invalidate the comment about its compatibility with _Scala_ 2.13). What does your pom.xml file look like? Can you add that to your post?

Comment: I added it but can I have another alternative to scalacheck to create generators ?

Comment: I wrote a wrong comment, that is only for aws emr not general sorry.

Comment: It seems that you may be using _Scala_ 2.12 (or earlier), but it's hard to say for sure because the _Scala_ version is not explicitly stated. However, you're definitely trying to use the 2.13 version of _ScalaCheck_. (_Scala_ binary compatibility changes with each minor release, so libraries need to be built for the version of _Scala_ being used.) There is no inherent problem with using _ScalaCheck_ for property-based testing. Try changing the dependency to be for `ScalaCheck_2.12` and see if that fixes it for you...

Comment: Thanks, I had `scala 2.12` so I have used `ScalaCheck 2.12` and I don't have errors when I compile.